# why does my background image doesn't show?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a problem which is my background image doesn't show up. I am sure that my url is correct (Because I have used this url in other aspects).

This is my css file:

```
body{
    background : url(assets/image/main.jpg);

    background-size: cover;


}
```

so what happened?

This is my folder's structure:

```
/assets/
      css/
         style.css
      image/
         main.jpg
/index.html
```

Comment: Your url is probably wrong. What happens when you open the url?

Comment: The URL should be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `background :` and add quotes to your URL string so it looks like `background: url("assets/image/main.jpg");`

Beyond that just ensure that the filepath from this css file still maps to that folder correctly, just because it works in one css file doesn't mean it works in another if the folder structure differs.

Comment: The space doesn't matter.

Comment: hi ! the folder structure hasn't changed. And it doesn't work

Comment: The quotes don't matter either. They are optional.

Comment: Space does matter, just not to the compiler, just to everyone that has to read it. I was not aware about the quotes though! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.
You should know that the path is relative to the location of the style (and not the html).
The fact of having used this code elsewhere does not mean that the path is correct here.

After that may be the image which is corrupt.

Comment: hi! The image doesn't corrupt and also the path is correct...

Comment: I believe this to be the right answer. Try this path: `../assets/image/main.jpg`

Comment: From [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url): The <url> data type is specified using the url() functional notation. It may be written without quotes, or surrounded by single or double quotes. Relative URLs are allowed, and are relative to the URL of the stylesheet (not to the URL of the web page).